# Can I use an Development certificate along with adhoc distribution provisioning profile to distribute my app to specific user?

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

I am trying to adhoc distribute my ios app. My admin to our dev portal created a adhoc dist provisioning profile. Can I use any cert(Dev or dist) to code sign my application? or it has to be dist cert? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer: you'll need a distribution certificate, with an ad-hoc provisioning profile that contains the target device's UDID. You can configure this on the [dev portal](https://developer.apple.com).

Development certificates are purely for device development at your own machine. It does give you access to a limited number of devices to build your app on, but it isn't ideal for beta testing an app on.

Distribution certs and ad-hoc profiles are most commonly used with services like [Fabric](http://fabric/io) to beta test your app. You may also want to look into [TestFlight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/) to help distribute for beta testing.

Good luck!